# Correct XSLT syntax for copying an XML file loaded using document()

Tags: xslt

I'm tearing my hair out with this one, any assistance appreciated.

What is the correct syntax for using document() to load an XML file into an XSLT for processing? Just to troubleshoot I've been using the following but nothing is output when I would expect the content of $File to be output. I can't figure out why? I feel I must be missing something obvious.

**The XML file being processed**

```
<FileUpload/>
```

**The XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="File"/>
<xsl:template match="/FileUpload">
    <FileUpload>
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document($File)/Root"/>
        </xsl:comment>
    </FileUpload>
</xsl:template>
```

**Content of $File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Root><RECORD/></Root>
```

**What I would expect to be output**

```
<FileUpload>
<!--<Root><Record/></Root>-->
</FileUpload>
```

**What is actually output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileUpload><!----></FileUpload>
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xsl:comment instruction, like xsl:attribute and xsl:text, turns your supplied XML node into a string by taking its string value. The string value of an element or document node is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes: in your example, there aren't any descendant text nodes, so the resulting comment is empty.

What you want is a comment whose content is the XML serialization of the document. In XSLT 3.0 you can do that with

```
<xsl:comment>{
  serialize(document($File), map{'method':'xml')
}</xsl:comment>
```

Alternatively, rather than parsing and reserializing the document, you could simply copy it in its unparsed state:

```
<xsl:comment>{
  unparsed-text($File)
}</xsl:comment>
```

In XSLT 1.0 you would need processor extensions to achieve this. Or you could use a serializer written in XSLT: see for example http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED 2**

Just use the options @MichaelKay has given.

Comment: Note that apart from the usual caveats about disable-output-escaping, this will fail if the copied document contains comments (or even if it contains two adjacent hyphens).

Comment: @MichaelKay. Correct, to make the solution deal with that , I will change the answer.

Comment: But now you're moving towards the solution of writing an XSLT serializer, so you might as well use one that exists, e.g. the one from Evan Lenz cited in my answer, or there's another from David Carlisle.

Comment: It is not easy to give up on an answer. But you'r correct, it's stupid to reinvent the wheel.